# Refresh call api after click on map

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, openweathermap, react-leaflet

I start in react and I want to make a system that when I click on my map produced by the module "React-Leaflet" to modify my Marker. After this click, I want to recall Api for refresh data to my component Weather.
How can I do ?
Can you help me please ?

Here is my component Weather :

```
import './Meteo.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { getLat, getLng } from '../../Store.js';

export default class Meteo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            temp: "",
            pressure: "",
            humidity: "",
            temp_min: "",
            temp_max: "",
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const lat = getLat();
        const lng = getLng();

        axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lng}&appid=${APIKEY}`)
            .then(res => {
                const meteo = res.data;
                console.log("Meteo" + meteo);
                this.setState({ 
                    temp: meteo.main.temp,
                    pressure: meteo.main.pressure,
                    humidity: meteo.main.humidity,
                    temp_min: meteo.main.temp_min,
                    temp_max: meteo.main.temp_max,
                });
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <p>Meteo</p>
        )
    };

}
```

Here is my component Map :

```
import './Map.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import L from "leaflet";
import { getLat, getLng, setLat, setLng } from '../../Store.js';

const customMarker = new L.icon({
  iconUrl: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/images/marker-icon.png",
  iconSize: [25, 41],
  iconAnchor: [13, 0]
});

export default class MapLeaflet extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            lat: getLat(),
            lng: getLng(),
        }
    }

    updateMarker = (e) => {
        setLat(e.latlng.lat);
        setLng(e.latlng.lng);
        this.setState({ 
            lat: e.latlng.lat,
            lng: e.latlng.lng,
        });
    }

    render() {
        const position = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng]
        return (
            <div className="map">
                <Map center={position} zoom={13} className="map" onClick={this.updateMarker} >
                    <TileLayer
                        attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                    />
                    <Marker position={position} icon={customMarker}>
                        <Popup>
                            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
                        </Popup>
                    </Marker>
                </Map>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And Here is my Store :

```
const coord = {
    lat: 51.505,
    lng: -0.09
}

export function getLat(){
    return coord.lat;
}

export function getLng(){
    return coord.lng;
}

export function setLat(lat){
    coord.lat = lat;
}

export function setLng(lng){
    coord.lng = lng;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is that you should move the coordinates and data to the parent component state then pass them as props to MapLeaflet and Meteo components. Create new methods which will update the coordinates on marker position update and then fetch the data. Here is an example https://codesandbox.io/s/x3p2kwnzvz - it is without the map and I use Math.random to generate data